# How can I acces to the content of the value attribute of a form select tag or to its inner text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, xhtml

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and I have some problem working on a form validation script.

So in my page I have some input field such as:

```
<input id="kmProjectInfo_name" class="" type="text" value="" size="19" name="kmProjectInfo.name">
```

and I use the following function to get the value from this input field using **document.getElementById('kmProjectInfo_name').value** and to check is this value is 
considerable valid for my pourpose:

```
function validateForm() {

    alert(document.getElementById('selectCountry').value)

    // VALIDAZIONE DEL PROJECT NAME:
    if( document.getElementById('kmProjectInfo_name').value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide a valid project name" );
        //document.myForm.Name.focus();
        document.getElementById('kmProjectInfo_name').focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Ok, this work fine but into my form I have also this field that need to be validate:

```
<select id="selectStatus" onchange="checkStatus(this)" name="kmProjectInfo.status.idProjectInfoStatus">
    <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option id="aui_3_2_0_1240" value="1">Closed</option>
    <option id="aui_3_2_0_1226" value="2">Active</option>
    <option value="3">Testing</option>
    <option value="4">Starting</option>
</select>
```

So now I need to accesse to the value into the **value** attribute (for example 0,1,2,3,4) or to the inner text of the option tag (for example: "-- Please Select --", "Closed", "Active", "Testing", "Starting").

Can I do this thing using JavaScript? How can I implement it?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  var el = document.getElementById("selectStatus");

  var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;  // get value (1, 2, 3, ...)
  var text  = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;  // get text (Closed, Starting....)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Javascript**

This allows to acces the `innerHtml` attribute and whatever its content is.

`var myInnerHtml = document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML;`

**Using JQuery**

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: How does accessing the `innerHTML` of a select help validate it?

Comment: My bad, I was a bit too quick to base my answer only on the title and tags.

Comment: innerHtml works, innerText don't works. Why? What exactly is the difference?

Comment: `innerText` isn't a valid property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the selected index of the `select` element, and then get the `option` value based on that:

```
var select = document.getElementById("kmProjectInfo_name");
var index = select.selectedIndex;

var value = select.options[index].value; //0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```